# Accesing contents of a file in java

Tags: java, filereader

I wanted to know if there is any method in java to access the contents of the file in the computer.

For example if I want to make a word guessing game in which I want to access the words kept in a file randomly.

(I heard of something called "FileReader" but can't understand how to use it.)

Hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks!!

Comment: google - how to read a file in java!

Comment: did you try googling it? goo.gl/SiJ7XT

Comment: Create an object of `FileReader` and pass the name of the file to its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can read contents of File like this.

```
public void readFile(String fileName){          //Pass file's absolute path
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line = null;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
         System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also read an entire text file as a List with Files.readAllLines . You can do it like this (read and print):

```
 List<String> sl= Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test1.txt"));
        for (String s:sl) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Another option is to use Files.newBufferedReader like this:

```
try (BufferedReader br= Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test1.txt"))) 
        {
            String line;
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) System.out.println(line);
        }
```

The try(){ } construct is called try-with-resorces, it closes the open file object (br in this case) automatically when finished. It is vital for writing, and is a good coding practice for reading.